# Why is it not possible to choose "Removed" state for some User Stories?

Tags: azure-devops

In our Azure DevOps are two different User Stories, for one it is possible to set the State to "Removed" and for the other it is not possible. Can you explain to me why it is like this?

I see no big difference between the User Stories except of the Area and iteration, even if I change the area it is still not possible to change the State to "Removed". Both user Stories are in the same project, the base iteration and the base area is the same:

1.: Missing State "Removed"
[image]

2.: Choosable State "Removed"
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'**`Removed`**' and '**`Closed`**' are two different final states for the work item.

- '**`Closed`**' generally means all the works planned in the work item have been finished. This work item can be closed.
- '**`Removed`**' generally means the planned works in the work item have not been finished, but you decide to cancel / stop all the plans. So, this work item is removed. Once you change the work item to '**`Removed`**' state, it will be hidden from the backlog and board.

[image]

You cannot directly change the state of the work item from '**`Closed`**' to '**`Removed`**'. Similarly, you also cannot directly change the state from '**`Removed`**' to '**`Closed`**'.

For more details, you can reference the following documents:

- [**Workflow states**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/workflow-and-state-categories?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#workflow-states)
- [**Remove work items**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=azure-devops#remove-work-items)

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that the state "Closed" is the reason. I can choose all states and it is possible to choose the state "Removed", but if the Story is in state "Closed", it is not possible to switch to "Removed". It is needed to switch to any other state first and save, then it is possible to choose "Removed".